# Seemingly tall man answers door but he's actually short

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

I'm trying to identify an 80's comedy that has a sketch in it along the following lines:

A gent approaches a timber door, either at a castle or a large wooden factory door, he taps on it and a high latch opens to ask his business, he explains himself and the door opens yet a very small man appears having answered the door high up.

Just reminds me of a classic film I can't quite put my finger on. Something tells me there was an 'Igor' type character in it but this may be wrong.

Possibly Top Secret? or Naked Gun? or Pink Panther series ?

Answer (score 18):

You *are* describing a scene from [Top Secret](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088286/combined): When Nick and Val reach the resistance, a high latch opens and a man appears through it. But when he opens the door, he's short (he's the guy on the left [here](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t31.0-8/s720x720/416724_10150761281565229_1656006208_o.jpg)). Here's the clip: